# Share IntelliJ inspection profile between different projects

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an inspection profile configured for one of my IntelliJ projects and have "Share profile" checked. When I'm in another project, the inspection profile I created is not available (doesn't appears in the dropdown combobox). Is there a way to create an inspection profile just once and use it across many projects?

I'm running IntelliJ 10.5.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shared profile option means that it will be stored in the project and is shared with other developers via the project files. If you **disable this option**, inspections profile will be stored in IntelliJ IDEA configuration directory on your machine and you'll be able to use the same profile in multiple projects.

See also [Inspections](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/inspections-2.html) help section:

> **Share profile** - Select this check box to make the selected profile available for your team, i.e to make it the project-level profile. If
>   you create IDE-level profile for your own purposes, clear this check
>   box.

Comment: Interesting, "Share profile" has exactly the opposite behavior that one might assume. I have to uncheck "Share profile" in order to share between projects.

Comment: Where is this "Share profile" option? I can't find it and I googled a lot.

Comment: UI has changed, use Manage | Copy to Project.