# Share IntelliJ analysis settings between developers for a Gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

We've got a Java project (with sub-projects) spread over a couple of git repositories.  There is a `build.gradle` for it all, and importing that into IntelliJ works very nicely, so until now we did not have a need for putting any IntelliJ configuration into git.

But it turns out that we want to specify inspection settings on a per project basis (Gradle calls them projects, IntelliJ calls them modules), and the best I've been able to do so far is to ask each developer to import inspection profiles, and to manually associate the right modules with the right profiles.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share IntelliJ inspection profile between different projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659937/share-intellij-inspection-profile-between-different-projects)

Comment: @Andrey I'm not sure.  My understanding is that the inspection profile is either stored in the IntelliJ configuration (outside of git) or it is stored in the `.idea` directory (which is also outside of git in our case).  Maybe we should store it in `.idea` and put `.idea` into git.  But I doubt that we want to put most of `.idea` into git -- for one thing it is auto-generated from importing `build.gradle` and maybe there are also user preferences in there (keyboard shortcuts?).

Comment: You do not need to put all files under .idea to git. For inspections you need to share the `inspectionProfiles` folder in the `.idea` directory.

Comment: Thank you @Andrey, I was not aware that it is so easy to put just parts of `.idea` into git.  (Who knows what the interdependencies are, I thought.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to the **Stored in Project** [inspection profile](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/customizing-profiles.html) and share the `inspectionProfiles` folder under the `.idea` project configuration directory with the team.